# .htaccess rewriting with the [P] proxy flag

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I am trying to do an invisible (transparent ?) rewrite via .htaccess and the proxy flag. It works with the [R] flag but not with the [P] flag because it just gives a 500 error. The two domains are on separate servers and the mod_proxy module is enabled. Is my .htaccess correct?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    =one.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://two.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Can you check the error log on the server that you're getting the 500 error on to see what the specific error was?

Comment: This is the error I get : ***.IP.***.*** - - [14/Sep/2010:19:33:11 +0200] "GET /149c9fad24f457143dcb HTTP/1.1" 500 433 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; fr-fr) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5"

Comment: That's from the access log though, there should be a separate error log that explains why Apache generated a 500 response.

Comment: Nope sorry, I don't have access to any other log...

Answer (score 8):

If `mod_proxy` was compiled as a shared module, it requires that you explicitly load the relevant submodules too. It's possible that on your server `mod_proxy_http` is not enabled, which leads to an internal server error when `mod_proxy` tries to handle the request passed to it by `mod_rewrite`.

`mod_proxy` itself is enabled and probably working like you said, since if you don't have it enabled, use of the `P` flag will just generate a 404 response. It's hard to know for sure though without the error log, so you may need to find someone with access to it to see what's going on to help you resolve the problem.

Comment: thanks for the note about the 404 -- I couldn't figure out why I was getting it!