# Redirect sub domain to other IP address without changing sub domain name getting internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, dns, redirect

I want to redirect from domain_name/directory_name/file_name/ to http://xx.xx.xx.x/project_name/controller/ but in URL I want to show domain_name/directory_name/file_name/. For that I write following code in .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !directory_name/file_name/$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xx.xx.xx.x/project_name/controller/$1 [P]
```

When I write

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !directory_name/file_name/$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xx.xx.xx.x/project_name/controller/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then it is redirect from directory_name/file_name/ to http://xx.xx.xx.x/project_name/controller/ but showing http://xx.xx.xx.x/project_name/controller/ in URL.

For that I change [L,R=301] to [P] as the reference of http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url site but it gives me following error

```
 Internal Server Error

 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable   to complete your request.

 Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

 More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Please help me.It would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer. 
Just enable your mod_proxy_http Apache module.

```
  Go to your httpd.conf file and uncomment proxy_http_module
  Restart wamp
```

Reference - [.htacess rewriting with the [P] proxy flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711189/htacess-rewriting-with-the-p-proxy-flag)